# Finding the most specific record - SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables Master - Detail and trying to find more relevant result based in input parameter

```
Create Table #Master(MasterId int, Method varchar(100))
Insert Into #Master Values(1,'MasterDefault')

Create Table #Detail(Id int, MasterId int,ATypeId int, BTypeId int,CTypeId int,DetailMethod varchar(100))
Insert Into #Detail
Values(1,1,1,1,1,'Detail All'),
      (2,1,null,1,1,'Detail ATypeId null'),
      (3,1,null,null,1,'Detail ATypeId and Btype null'),
      (4,1,null,null,null,'Detail all null')
```

Started something like below  (What I want to find is the Method only, either from master or detail)

```
declare @Id int =1,
        @AtypeId int =1,
        @BtypeId int=1,
        @CtypeId int =1

Select *
from #Master M
    left outer join #Detail D on M.MasterId = D.MasterId
Where M.MasterId = @Id
    AND ((D.ATypeId=@AtypeId) OR (D.ATypeId IS NULL))     
    AND ((D.BTypeId=@BtypeId) OR (D.BTypeId IS NULL))     
    AND ((D.CTypeId=@CtypeId) OR (D.CTypeId IS NULL))
```

In this case would like to return the Detail - Id 1 records as all the input match with detail row1

Id the parameters like below

```
declare @Id int =1,
        @AtypeId int =null,
        @BtypeId int=1,
        @CtypeId int =1
```

Would expect the row from detail with Id 2

Any help on achieving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `AND/OR` logic will work for you.

```
SELECT *
FROM   #Master M
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #Detail D
                    ON M.MasterId = D.MasterId
                       AND ( D.ATypeId = @AtypeId
                              OR ( @AtypeId IS NULL
                                   AND AtypeId IS NULL ) )
                       AND ( D.BTypeId = @BtypeId
                              OR ( @BtypeId IS NULL
                                   AND BtypeId IS NULL ) )
                       AND ( D.CTypeId = @CtypeId
                              OR ( @CtypeId IS NULL
                                   AND CtypeId IS NULL ) )
WHERE  M.MasterId = @Id
```

**Note:** I have moved the right table filters to `ON` condition since you have used `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. When you use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and filter the right table records in `Where` clause then it will be implicitly converted to `INNER JOIN`